# Сильнее, чем я себя, любит меня только она

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Comment: Запятые-то верно расставлены, а вот ситуация какая-то неправильная, искренне жаль ту, которая любит такого самовлюбленного эгоиста, потребителя чужой любви.

Answer (score 1):

**Сильнее, чем я себя, любит меня только она.**

Знаки поставлены верно, но вызывает сомнение корректность и необходимость  такой инверсии. Такой вариант должен сочетаться с контекстом вида "я себя очень люблю".

Нейтральный  вариант: **Только она любит меня сильнее, чем я сам себя.** Здесь контекст такой: она очень меня любит.

Примеры:

― И добавил заботливо: ― И ты себя должен беречь, даже, может быть, **больше, чем я себя.** [Вадим Кожевников. Щит и меч. Книга первая (1968)]

Он знал меня **лучше, чем я сам себя.** [Анатолий Гладилин. Прогноз на завтра (1972)]